# Failed to connect to mysql container from another container in the same Docker network

Tags: mysql, docker

I have 3 Docker containers. One running a nodejs app, one running mysql and one running redis. They are in the same (default) network.

```
root@online-chess:~# docker inspect mysql -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
{"app_default":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":["mysql","e89159b03ea0"],"NetworkID":"4559baadffb3bb25beb74e63d3ffcf1df3acfdac7fd496d28a20747f55153447","EndpointID":"844932c4542c6aab74dda6571477c1fd51743a4a890dc25792e80262aad55f7f","Gateway":"172.27.0.1","IPAddress":"172.27.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:1b:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}
root@online-chess:~# docker inspect redis -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
{"app_default":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":["redis","9e5c1cb5c0ab"],"NetworkID":"4559baadffb3bb25beb74e63d3ffcf1df3acfdac7fd496d28a20747f55153447","EndpointID":"8de49f7eb5c1ccc428d1e27da841033b548c3bf75ef5d60d196d65d5bbde8b38","Gateway":"172.27.0.1","IPAddress":"172.27.0.2","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:1b:00:02","DriverOpts":null}}
root@online-chess:~# docker inspect game -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
{"app_default":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":null,"Aliases":["game","18e7eeb3fd65"],"NetworkID":"4559baadffb3bb25beb74e63d3ffcf1df3acfdac7fd496d28a20747f55153447","EndpointID":"4158b7ef6fc66006e19be58c6f29633dfce1742e3327c76765d116c2ff243c1a","Gateway":"172.27.0.1","IPAddress":"172.27.0.4","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:1b:00:04","DriverOpts":null}}
```

I try to connect to mysql from the nodejs app but failed.

Here's the connection parameters:

```
const db=mysql.createConnection({
        user: 'root',
        host:  mysql,
        password: 'password',
        database: online_chess,
        port: 3306
    // user,host,password,port,database
})
```

When I review the `docker logs` of the nodejs container after starting all containers (I'm printing the error message in server.js):

```
root@online-chess:/app# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                  NAMES
0aa397f6beac   app_game   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   9 seconds ago    Up 8 seconds    0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp              game
39ef715e9b2d   mysql      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql
2912223e0281   redis      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 minutes ago   Up 12 minutes   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp              redis
root@online-chess:/app# docker logs 0aa397f6beac

> online-chess-starting-files@1.0.0 start
> node server.js

server started at http://localhost:5000
Connected to redis...
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:205:17)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

Here's the nodejs container's docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  game:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    container_name: game
    environment:
      PORT: 5000
```

Here's the mysql's docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      # MYSQL_USER: testuser
      # MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      # MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: online_chess
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysql
volumes:
  db_data:
```

I can't figure out what's wrong. Thank you for any help!

Comment: You need to quote your string literals in the connection parameters. You have quoted `'root'` and `'password'` but not `mysql` and `online_chess`.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately doesn't work. I'm actually using Google Cloud SQL as replacement now and the connection is successful without quoting any connection parameter